# How to correctly print a pandas dataframe column received over TCP stream?

Tags: python, pandas, multithreading

I am getting the following error while trying to print a column from a dataframe.

```
raise KeyError(f"None of [{key}] are in the [{axis_name}]")
KeyError: "None of [Index(['1'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"
```

I have tried to print the columns first using
`df.columns` attribute and i get the correct or expected output below:

```
Index(['1', '2'], dtype='object')
```

I have tried the below code for the attempt of the print

```
print(posdf[['1']])
```

I also tried a couple of things as well but couldn't print.

**the thing is that the data frame created is a received stream over TCP which i convert it to the following shape using different threads one thread for receiving another thread for refining the data and printing the required column:**

```
{
    "1": {
            "obj_id": [11, 12, 13, 14], 
            "creation_time": [1701174621516041, 1701174621516041, 1701174621516041, 1701174621516041], 
            "frame_count": [341, 222, 333, 444], 
            "classification": ["PERSON", "PERSON", "PERSON", "PERSON"], 
            "velocity": [{"x": 11, "y": 11, "z": 11}, {"x": 12, "y": 12, "z": 12}, {"x": 13, "y": 13, "z": 13}, {"x": 14, "y": 14, "z": 14}], 
            "position": [{"x": 11, "y": 11, "z": 11}, {"x": 12, "y": 12, "z": 12}, {"x": 13, "y": 13, "z": 13}, {"x": 14, "y": 14, "z": 14}], 
            "heading": [11, 12, -37.560306549072266, 14]
        }, 
    "2": {
            "obj_id": [21, 22, 23, 24], 
            "creation_time": [1701174621516041, 1701174621516041, 1701174621516041, 1701174621516041], 
            "frame_count": [341, 22, 23, 444], 
            "classification": ["PERSON", "PERSON", "PERSON", "PERSON"], 
            "velocity": [{"x": 21, "y": 21, "z": 21}, {"x": 22, "y": 22, "z": 22}, {"x": 23, "y": 23, "z": 23}, {"x": 24, "y": 24, "z": 24}], 
            "position": [{"x": 21, "y": 21, "z": 21}, {"x": 22, "y": 22, "z": 22}, {"x": 23, "y": 23, "z": 23}, {"x": 24, "y": 24, "z": 24}], 
            "heading": [21, -37.560306549072266, -37.560306549072266, 24]
        }
},
```

after this shape i refine it and get only the data i am interested in as below

```
    {
      "1": [{"x": 11, "y": 11, "z": 11}, {"x": 12, "y": 12, "z": 12}, {"x": 13, "y": 13,"z":13}, {"x": 14, "y": 14, "z": 14}], 
      "2": [{"x": 21, "y": 21, "z": 21}, {"x": 22, "y": 22, "z": 22}, {"x": 23, "y": 23, "z": 23}, {"x": 24, "y": 24, "z": 24}]
   }
```

the data are not real values `"1"` and `"2"` are time stamps for the received frame, and for the values the first digit refers to the time stamp and the second digit for the object number.
from the above shape i create the data frame

```
posdf =  pd.DataFrame(pos)
```

when i print this data frame i get

```
                             1                            2
0  {'x': 11, 'y': 11, 'z': 11}  {'x': 21, 'y': 21, 'z': 21}
1  {'x': 12, 'y': 12, 'z': 12}  {'x': 22, 'y': 22, 'z': 22}
2  {'x': 13, 'y': 13, 'z': 13}  {'x': 23, 'y': 23, 'z': 23}
3  {'x': 14, 'y': 14, 'z': 14}  {'x': 24, 'y': 24, 'z': 24}
```

now when i try to print column `"1"` i get the error stated at the top.

**this is the code of the thread i used to process the data frame:**

```
def processing_from_queue(lock:threading.Lock):
"""
    param: lock to protect shared resources (TIMESTAMP)
    
    return: None

    Description: read from TIMESTAMP and refine data 
                 creates a dictionary its key is the timestamp
                 and its values are lists of the data.
                 ex:{'1': [{'x': 11, 'y': 11, 'z': 11}, {'x': 12, 'y': 12, 'z': 12}, {'x': 13, 'y': 13, 'z': 13}, {'x': 14, 'y': 14, 'z': 14}], 
                     '2': [{'x': 21, 'y': 21, 'z': 21}, {'x': 22, 'y': 22, 'z': 22}, {'x': 23, 'y': 23, 'z': 23}, {'x': 24, 'y': 24, 'z': 24}]}
"""
vel = {}
pos = {}
hed = {}
while True:
    
    logging.info("Active current thread right now: %s", (threading.current_thread().name))
    with lock:
        if (TIMESTAMP != {}):
            logging.info('lock is acquired from%s',threading.current_thread())
            logging.info('from processing thread%s,%s,%s',ssl_thread.is_alive(),reading_thread.is_alive(),process_thread.is_alive())
            for key in TIMESTAMP.keys():
                vel.update({key:TIMESTAMP[str(key)]['velocity']})
                pos.update({key:TIMESTAMP[str(key)]['position']})
                hed.update({key:TIMESTAMP[str(key)]['heading']})
        else:
            logging.info('no time stamp found')
        
        """
            processing of data frame begins here
            problem in implementing correct shape of dataframe 
            that depends on the timestamp to perfomr required calculations
            to predict if object is going to collide with each other
            or wether they have collided already.
        """
        # veldf = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(vel)
        posdf =  pd.DataFrame(pos)
        #heddf = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(pos)
        print(posdf)
        # print(posdf[['1']])
    logging.info("lock is released from processing thread position df is %s", posdf)
```

Comment: If you want to print the column `"1"` then it's `print(posdf["1"])` with a single pair of square brackets.

Comment: @alec_djinn i tried it as well but gives me this error `    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: '1'`

Comment: actually i separated the data frame alone in another script and tried to print the column it prints as expected with no errors i don't know why in this script it gives an error that's why i shared the thread that process the data frame.

Answer (score 0):

since i am using multithreading the thread that is dealing with the dataframe was trying to print an empty data frame, the thread which is responsible for filling the data frame takes a while since it receives from the stream.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).